# Quaternions' adding, subtracting and division operations on 3d models

Tags: 3d, quaternions, graphics3d

I just dig a bit deeper in use of quaternions in 3D game programming (Yes, I know about matrices and they are OK, but we always have to learn some new things), so, we can rotate some object like this `Pout = q*Pin*conjug(q)`, where are q is quaternion, Pin is an object of(let's say we are using some framework, where this class is defined for us) the Vector3 class, `conjug(q)` is the q quaternion after the its conjugating and, finally, `Pout` is the new Vector3's object, which we got after the rotation initial Vector3's object `Pin` by some angle alfa(or theta, whatever you like). Also, I know there is a way to combine rotations, like so: `q_final = q2*q1` (this represents rotating by the alfa1 and then by the alfa2 angles). And, finally, dot product represents the angle between 2 quaternions in, let's say, sphere. This is clear for me. My question will concern such things as division, adding and subtracting.

**My question is**: Could anybody tell me, please, what are they(division, adding, subtracting -operations on quaternions) representing in a 3D programming? How they will affect on 3D model?

Thank you beforehand for your answers.

**p.s.** If you (***DarenW, bensiu, Dharmendra, Uwe Keim, Jennis***) can't understand this question, please, leave this topic. Someone might have an answer. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quaternions' adding, subtructing and division operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127684/quaternions-adding-subtructing-and-division-operations)

Comment: True, but that question was closed, and I for one disagree that this question is vague.  It is asking a good questions about a very important tool in 3d graphics.  As a frequent contributor to graphics and geometry questions, I would ask that someone protect this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you know, quaternions are identifiable with 4x4 real matrices.  Quaternion multiplication, scalar multiplication and addition is preserved by this identification (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations).  So converting two quaternions to 4x4 matrices, adding them, and converting them back is the same as just adding them.  The same thing is true for multiplication.

Division of quaternion A by quaternion B is nothing more than multiplying A by the multiplicative inverse of B.  This is equivalent to the matrix form of A multiplied by the inverse of the matrix form of B.

Note that rigid-body rotations (no shearing or scaling) are represented by **unit length** quaternions.  So you can accumulate rotations by multiplying unit quaterions.  Addition in this case isn't as useful.

Finally, the main reason we use quaterions in graphics is in interpolating key frames (e.g. [*Eberly* 1999](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/KeyframeAnimation.pdf)).  That is, if we know the desired rotations at *k* positions, we can interpolate the quaterions, e.g. with a spline, resulting in a quaternion-valued curve.  Each value C(t) is a unit quaternion, so it represents an intermediate rotation.  Key frame interpolation is harder with homogeneous matrices because not all 4x4 matrices represent homogeneous transforms: The interpolation process may add scaling, shearing, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I was searching for this kind of explanation through different manuals very long time. But most of them were only about multiplication.